# Is it possible to print to a Brother MFC-490CW that is conected to a LAN

Tags: networking, printing

I have a Brother MFC-490CW printer that is connected to my LAN (wireless) and on which I can print with fine from Windows. From Ubuntu however, it does not seem to be possible. I downloaded and installed cups and lpd drivers from the Brother site and installed them. I get a Brother printer that says it is connected via USB. If I search for a network printer, my printer is shown. If I select it and select the correct driver, I can submit test pages. These pages are however not printed.

What could be wrong. Should it really be that much harder then it is on Windows?

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem brother using the CUPS and LPR drivers and trying to install them through the UBUNTU printer install interface.  I also tried the CUPS webpage trick with no success.  After several days and methods of trying to get it to work, I finally had success using the brother installer package located here:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/us/us/en/dlf/dlf/000000/006800/dlf006893.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc490cw_all&type2=91&os=128&flang=4&dlid=dlf006893

You have to use some terminal commands when using this method, but there are only about 7 or 8 of them and the instructions right below the installer package download link are pretty clear.  It wasn't as bad as I thought.  Once I saw all of the dependent packages the Brother installer downloaded to support the installation, I realized there was no way I was going to make this work using the typical Youtube simple install methods.

Hope this helps you or someone else who had the same difficulties I did.

Comment: No please, include those instructions **here** in the answer. Users shouldn't have to read another resources except to look for references.